# Boundary of a set

Tags: general-topology

Can boundary of any subset of $\mathbb R$ under the usual topology be $[0,1]$? I think it is not possible. If $\partial A=[0,1]$, then $[0,1]\subset \overline{A}$ and $[0,1]\cap A^{0}=\emptyset$. Then what to do? Please give some hint.

Comment: Hint: think *rationally*.

Comment: It's a nice exercise to show that *every* closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the boundary of some set. See, for example WILLARD, "General Topology", exercise 3B.

Comment: @ Mathemaicos Chibchas:Now I got the meaning of "rationally".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the boundary of a dense set with empty interior is its closure (Can you prove this?).

So, in this case, you can take $A = \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$.

Comment: @ P. vaidyanathan: I think boundary of any set with empty interior is the closure of the set.